# Static Resource Image is not displaying in LWC

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I'm unable to display the static resource Images in HTML by using LWC. Below is the file. Please guide me to fix this issue.

**HTML**

```
<lightning-card> <img src={profilePic}/> </lightning-card>
```

**JS File**

```
  import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
    import staticResourceImage from  '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Static_Images';
    export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
        profilePic = staticResourceImage+'/avatar.png' ;
    }
```

Static Resource:
[Static Resource Created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rut0j.png)

[Static Resource Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCKil.png)

[Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOAgl.png)

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

remove /avatar.png update code as
profilePic = staticResourceImage;